# Multiple category filters

Tags: metabox, taxonomy

I'm working on an events plugin for a client and I need several 'categories filters'. Now I have arguments for a post type, I've registered that post type and taxonomy, and I created another taxonomy. In my category metabox I only have the first taxonomy displayed as a category that I can choose from. If I create another post type on my menus it will be shown like a different plugin menu with submenus where my post type is, and I only want to have a different 'category filter' that I can add categories to, and then for those to be displayed as a category metabox in the same plugin.

So for now I have a post type and taxonomy for 'Place', that shows in my plugin in a place where a category metabox usually is. And in my plugin submenu I can go to Place and add several 'categories' (places). I also have 'Area of work' taxonomy, and I'd like to have another metabox that looks like the category metabox (in the same page) where I'll also be able to add different areas, and then check them accordingly, along with my 'Place' category.

Is that possible? How to add a submenu where I'll be able to add my second categories, and then have them displayed in the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Found it out!

I needed to put the registered taxonomy to the same post type in the `registered_taxonomy()` function.